# EF6 issues. Can't add new object in the database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to use EF6 in my win form app. In my code when I'm adding a new object in the db I'm getting the null reference exception.
Actually Products property in the method InitNewProducts is null. What am i doing wrong?

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace DAL
{
    public class CartContext: DbContext
    {
        public CartContext(): base("DbConnection")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Product> Products;
    }
}

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DAL
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set;}
    }
}

private void InitNewProducts()
{
    using (var context = new CartContext())
    {
        var product1 = new Product {Id = 1, Name = "SomeProduct1", CartItems = new List<CartItem> {new CartItem {Id = 1} } };
        context.Products.Add(product1);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error when you are connecting to the database or just from the query?  You may want to start debugging by finding out if the connection string is correct.  I don't see any opening of the database connection in the existing code.

Answer (score 1):

Add accessors to `DbSet<Product>`:

```
public virtual DbSet<Product> Products {get; set;}
```

Comment: Just needed to change the fields to properties, but thank you, for your help

Comment: @user3525444 sorry, I didn't understand what you meant, was this not the reason? Adding `{get; set;}` should have solved your issue.

Comment: Sorry, of course you completely right. I meant the virtual modifier.

Comment: @user3525444 oh right, no problems, the `virtual` modifier is if you want    the lazy loading, I just typed it out of instinct. (although I think if you use ef core - that doesn't matter at all as it doesn't support lazy loading last time i checked)

Comment: Just for information, lazy loading will be available with [EF Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1).